# Mongodb dump size too smaller than it was in the database

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I want migrate old Mongodb2.6.8 database to new Mongodb4.4. So I tried mongodump to backup below "okapp" database.

```
[okapp@centos101 bin]$ ./bin/mongo localhost:27018
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8
connecting to: localhost:27001/test
> show dbs
admin    (empty)
okapp    6.497GB
ca423    0.031GB
local    0.031GB
>
```

As you can see okapp size is 6.497GB. But after i run below:

```
./mongodump -h localhost:27001 -d okapp
```

And I will get a the dump:

```
2021-11-02T15:47:14.550+0100 DATABASE: okapp to     dump/okapp
2021-11-02T15:47:14.550+0100    okapp.system.indexes to dump/okapp/system.indexes.bson
2021-11-02T15:47:14.551+0100             5 documents
2021-11-02T15:47:14.551+0100    okapp.findjobsee to dump/okapp/findjobsee.bson
2021-11-02T15:47:14.551+0100             10 documents
2021-11-02T15:47:14.551+0100    Metadata for okapp.findjobsee to dump/okapp/findjobsee.metadata.json
2021-11-02T15:47:14.552+0100    okapp.findtasksee to dump/okapp/findtasksee.bson
2021-11-02T15:47:14.552+0100             0 documents
2021-11-02T15:47:14.552+0100    Metadata for okapp.findtasksee to dump/okapp/findtasksee.metadata.json
2021-11-02T15:47:14.552+0100    okapp.findresultsee to dump/okapp/findresultsee.bson
2021-11-02T15:47:14.614+0100             2937 documents
2021-11-02T15:47:14.614+0100    Metadata for okapp.findresultsee to dump/okapp/findresultsee.metadata.json
2021-11-02T15:47:14.615+0100    okapp.findjobarchivesee to dump/okapp/findjobarchivesee.bson
2021-11-02T15:47:14.618+0100             751 documents
2021-11-02T15:47:14.618+0100    Metadata for okapp.findjobarchivesee to dump/okapp/findjobarchivesee.metadata.json

[okapp@centos101 somedir]$ cd ./mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.8/dump/okapp
[okapp@centos101 somedir]$ du -sh  okapp
7.7MB okapp
[okapp@centos101 somedir]$ cd ./mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.8/dump/okapp
[okapp@centos101 okapp]$ du -sh *
316K    findalljobarchivesee.bson
4.0K    findalljobarchivesee.metadata.json
4.0K    findalljobsee.bson
4.0K    findalljobsee.metadata.json
7.4M    findallresultsee.bson
4.0K    findallresultsee.metadata.json
0       findalltasksee.bson
4.0K    findalltasksee.metadata.json
4.0K    system.indexes.bson
[okapp@centos101 okapp]$ 
[okapp@centos101 okapp]$
```

Note: i've checked the collections in the Mongodb

```
> db.findjobarchivesee.count()
751
> db.findjobsee.count()
10
> db.findresultsee.count()
2937
> db.findtasksee.count()
0
> db.system.indexes.count()
5
```

Anyone know why the size shrink too much? It was 6.497GB in database, but it just a 7.7 MB after  mongodump.

Comment: The `show dbs` command also includes the cache and index data stored on your machine. These are excluded while taking `mongodump`, Also, the mongo dump performs some internal compression of repeating data which is why the dump size is very small. Looking at your various collection counts, I am not surprised by the 7.7 MB size (it's the right size as per my knowledge). But regardless, I am not able to justify how you got around 6.5 GB! even if you have indexed all the keys, that value is just insane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few things that contribute to the difference:

- MMAP does not compact.  The size reported by `show dbs` includes empty space in the files, which may be due to documents being deleted.
- MongoDB with MMAP pads each document so there is free space between them to allow for documents to grow.  This padding will not be included with the documents when exported.
- `mongodump` does not export index data.  It exports the information that mongorestore will need in order to recreate the index at restore time.

Comment: Nice answer @Joe, Are you `Joe Karlsson` from MongoDB? I am just curious, please reply if you are comfortable with it :)

Comment: No, he is not me.